# Understanding Ansible Privledge Escalation and Fetch Module Execution

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to wrap my brain around how ansible's privledge escalation works in combination with the "fetch" module.
I have an ansible controller which I run a playbook as root on. The playbook fetches a file which is owned by root and is not world readable. My ansible.cfg (or playbook) has `remote_user=ansible, become=yes, become_user=root`. This playbook works, but I don't understand which user actually initializes the copy from the host to the controller.

The root user is configured to have access to the ansible user's SSH keys but `PermitRootLogin No` is set in my sshd_conf on both my controller and host so all ssh connections must be done using the ansible user even though the files are owned by root. I suspect my lack of understanding is related to how ssh tunnels work but I'm not entirely sure what to google here.

Below is a very crude example of what I'm trying to understand.

```
---
- name: Testing
  hosts: server1
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Fetch File
    fetch:
      src: /var/log/messages
      dest: /home/myuser/server1_messages
      flat: yes
```

Comment: Use option ``-vvvv`` to ``enable connection debugging``.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the output with -vvvv. It does show that it uses the ansible user for the ssh connection back to my controller. Perhaps that's the answer to my question? Fetch creates an SSH connection back to my controller and respects the remote_user option?

Comment: What *'``ssh connection back to (your) controller``'* are you talking about?